# Why infinity loop does not take cpu usage to 100

Tags: c#

When I run a simple c# program with a empty while loop, my cpu usage goes up from 8-12% to 24-20% and core usage pattern is almost identical.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        while(flag)
        {

        }
    }
```

Could anyone please explain this behavior. I was expecting one core usage goes to 100% at this time.

Update: I am using octa-core machine and total cpu usage (summing up all core usage) goes to 25%. And each core (leaving the first one) shows similar usage pattern (which is around 25%)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using a octa-core, if it was octa it would be 8, you are only showing 4 cpus. Are you sure you don't maybe have a 4 core machine with Hyper Threading?

Comment: Yes, It is an octa core machine. On the image, I only captured 4 of them.

Comment: All cores get their fair share of doing nothing. Most of the load is probably the switching.

Comment: @TaW The OS will switch a single threaded application from one core to another on the fly? Wouldn't this create unreasonable caching issues, especially when it switches to a core on an entirely different socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is single threaded. You probably have a Quad core CPU. You are likely maxing out the single core.

To fully max out modern multi-core CPUs you would need a multithreaded workload. In addition you would have to avoid optimizations if you get too cute with your code.

Comment: make sense. But why load is shared among all the cores and cpu usage pattern in almost identical? Ideally when load is one core 1 then all other core should not show any cpu spike?

Comment: I have programs that peg a single core at 100%, and I thought it would be easy to write a trivial `while` loop to do the same thing. But OP's code does not do this, nor does adding "actual" work inside the while loop (and referencing it elsewhere so it doesn't get optimized away); I mean some sqrt's and stuff. I agree with your intuition, but it's not the case for OP or me that a `while (true)` will peg even a single core.

Comment: If I create 8 different thread and run this code in each thread, my cpu does reach to 100%. But question is when it was run on single thread, by all core's usage pattern was same? Why does OS switch this allocation from one core to another and on same time?

Comment: Yes. The Operating System (Windows likely for you) cooperatively schedules threads and manages which thread gets time when, on which core. Typically an application thread stays on one core unless it asks otherwise. This is for efficiency of the state that the program has built up.

Comment: But my test application does not stay on one core. It keeps on shifted from one core to another. That is why one core does not reach to 100 but usage is distribute among all the cores?

Comment: Like I said, it is up to the O/S to decide which core it schedules it for. Since your program has 0 state, it may switch cores more often than another with lots of built up state information. If you open up task manager in newer windows versions you can "pin" the program to one core and force it to schedule it on that one core.

Answer (score 2):

As your application is monothreaded, you will only use one core. If it tops at 25%, I can guess the running environment is equipped with a quad-code processor.